# Nested ViewControllers in storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, nsviewcontroller

I'd like to nest my ViewController classes within their relevant data structures, like so:

```
struct Book {

    let title: String

}

extension Book {

    struct Chapter {

        let id: String

    }

}

extension Book.Chapter {

    class ViewController: NSViewController {

        var chapter: Book.Chapter!

    }

}
```

so that I can then refer to them as `Book.Chapter.ViewController` (instead of `BookChapterViewController`).

However, it seems that once I do so, I can no longer use my ViewController classes within storyboards. They don't appear in the custom class selection menu and entering manually into the storyboard XML has no effect. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating another `ViewController` class by going to `File > New > File...` and name it something like `MyViewController`, link it to your `StoryBoard`, and then make the class of your `extension Book.Chapter` a subclass of `MyViewController`?

Never tried it before but I think it'll work. Tell me how it goes :)

Comment: No dice :/ I can use the regular `MyViewController` class, but not `Book.Chapter.ViewController`.